# how can i used to loop in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I'm newbie jquery..

I don't know how can I compacted code for loop.

I have been saw the many code.

```
$('#fadeandscale1').popup({
    pagecontainer: '.container',
    transition: 'all 0.3s'
});
$('#fadeandscale2').popup({
    pagecontainer: '.container',
    transition: 'all 0.3s'
});
$('#fadeandscale3').popup({
    pagecontainer: '.container',
    transition: 'all 0.3s'
});
$('#fadeandscale4').popup({
    pagecontainer: '.container',
    transition: 'all 0.3s'
});
$('#fadeandscale5').popup({
    pagecontainer: '.container',
    transition: 'all 0.3s'
});
$('#fadeandscale6').popup({
    pagecontainer: '.container',
    transition: 'all 0.3s'
});
$('#fadeandscale7').popup({
    pagecontainer: '.container',
    transition: 'all 0.3s'
});
$('#fadeandscale8').popup({
    pagecontainer: '.container',
    transition: 'all 0.3s'
});
```

Comment: better if you use a class

Answer (score 2):

You can use the css3 selector   `[attribute^=value]` that selects a element based on the beginning of a attribute, the `id` for us

```
 $('div[id^="fadeandscale"]').popup({ pagecontainer: '.container', transition: 'all 0.3s' })
```

Comment: What is OP wants to exclude `#fadeandscale10`?

Comment: choes other div id for it

Comment: `$('div[id^="fadeandscale"]:not(div[id$="10"])')`

Comment: What is `id` starts with `fadeandscale`?

Comment: `$('div[id^="fadeandscale"]:not(div[id$="le"])')`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `loop` for this, you can provide multiple comma-separated selectors as follow:

```
$('#fadeandscale1, #fadeandscale2, #fadeandscale3, #fadeandscale4, #fadeandscale5, #fadeandscale6, #fadeandscale7, #fadeandscale8').popup({
    pagecontainer: '.container',
    transition: 'all 0.3s'
});
```

I'll recommend you to use common `class` to all the elements of interest and use it as selector.

```
$('.fadeElems').popup({
    pagecontainer: '.container',
    transition: 'all 0.3s'
});
```